# window.open() is blocked in browser iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

We have an Angular 13 app which is being tested within an **iframe** that is **hosted** in another application.

There are a few functions in our web app that DO NOT work, however. One is our printing routine which uses `window.open()` .

For example, clicking on this print icon: [image]

opens a javascript window where the user can finally choose "Print" [image]

The print routine in our TypeScript component looks like this (the first 30+ lines just set a bunch of vars):

```js
printAll(...) {

   ... // JUST SET A BUNCH OF VARIABLES ..

   const html = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link href="assets/dependencies/print/print.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script>
                function showHeader(ele) {
                    const headers = document.getElementsByClassName("rept-header");
                    if (ele.checked) {
                        for (const header of headers) {
                            header.classList.remove("no-display");
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (const header of headers) {
                            header.classList.add("no-display");
                        }
                    }
                }
                function showFooter(ele) {
                    const footers = document.getElementsByClassName("rept-footer");
                    if (ele.checked) {
                        for (const footer of footers) {
                            footer.classList.remove("no-display");
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (const footer of footers) {
                            footer.classList.add("no-display");
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <section id="print-menu" class="no-print">
                <div>
                    <button onclick="window.print()" class="primary-button">Print</button>
                    <button onclick="window.close()" class="secondary-button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                ${this.printHeaderHtml}
            </section>
            <section id="articles">
                ${images.join("<div class='print-break'></div>")}
            </section>
        </body>
        `;

        const features = [
            'status=0',
            'resizable=1',
            'scrollbars=0',
            'toolbar=0',
            'left=50',
            'top=50',
            `height=${screen.availHeight - 200}`,
            `width=${screen.availWidth - 200}`,
        ];

        const printPreviewWindow = window.open('', 'PrintPreview', features.join(','));
        printPreviewWindow.document.write(html);
        printPreviewWindow.document.close();
        printPreviewWindow.focus();
    }
```

So it possible to get around this **window.open()** blocking issue?

I've seen a blog where two ***iframes*** are being used to communicate with each other, but still not sure if that technique would solve this window.open() blocking issue. i.e. https://dev.to/damcosset/iframes-and-communicating-between-applications-31k5

---

Console Error, once the user clicks on Print option

And the document elements under the **iframe**:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you can't open a window in a different domain while retaining a reference to that window... you could add error details

Comment: @Drenai updated screen shots above. Indeed the window ref is Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the following code, and now I can see my new iframe to the bottom of body.
I can hide my  element temporarily UNTIL the user is done printing. Then show the top again.

```js
const iframetest = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframetest);
iframetest.setAttribute("style","height:100%;width:100%;");
iframetest.contentWindow.document.open();
iframetest.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframetest.contentWindow.document.close();
```

[image]